# Using .data pronoun twice in lapply optional arguments

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to use a lapply function that passes the list item to two arguments in FUN.

For example, given that:

```
> lapply(state.abb, paste, c(.data, 2))
[[1]]
[1] "AL 2"

[[2]]
[1] "AK 2"
```

Here I can pass the list argument `.data` and 2 to the `paste` function. But in my application I want to pass `.data` to both `paste` arguments. In my imagination this would be the code and output:

```
>lapply(state.abb, paste, c(.data, .data))
[[1]]
[1] "AL AL"

[[2]]
[1] "AK AK"
```

But what I get instead is

```
> lapply(state.abb, paste, c(.data, .data))
[[1]]
[1] "AL "

[[2]]
[1] "AK "
```

I *can* in this instance supply state.abb again, but in my actual use case this is part of a much larger data set and I'm trying to avoid naming objects as much as possible.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: `Map(paste, state.abb, state.abb)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.data` pronoun is a tidyverse (dplyr/ggplot2) thing. It does not work with base functions like `lapply`. (in fact if you ran that code without loading `dplyr` or `ggplot2` you should get an "object not found" error).  The `.data` basically defined to be just an empty list if any other functions use it so it's not doing anything for you. So these are all the exact same

```
lapply(state.abb, paste, c(.data, 2))
lapply(state.abb, paste, c(list(), 2))
lapply(state.abb, paste, list(2))
```

If you want to use the same parameter multiple times with `lapply`, then you would need to write your own function

```
lapply(state.abb, function(x) paste(x, x))
```

or you could use the `purrr::map` function and use `.x` for the data with the formula syntax for your function

```
purrr::map(state.abb, ~paste(.x, .x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function :

```
lapply(state.abb, function(x) paste(x, x))
```

OR `paste` and then make it a list.

```
as.list(paste(state.abb, state.abb))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not neccessarily a better solution than the ones above, but another:

```
Map(function(state.abb, i) paste(i, state.abb), state.abb, state.abb)
```